# How to use KUnit to test external modules?

Tags: unit-testing, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I want to write unit tests for an external module that I developed. How to use [KUnit](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/dev-tools/kunit/index.html) to test [external modules](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/kbuild/modules.html)?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your module dir/Makefile, add test cases object to obj-m var

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).